# What is the shelf life of herbal ghee: at room temp, fridge, or freezer?

Tags: storage-lifetime, spices, butter, herbs

What is the shelf life of herbal ghee?  At room temperature?  In the refrigerator?  In the freezer?  (Does ghee even freeze well?)

Comment: what do you mean with "herbal ghee"? Did you make ghee and then mix it with fresh herbs?  Ghee normally does not need to be refrigerated, it is more like oil then like butter, but with the addition of herbs I would probably keep it in the fridge